# why do i can't launch the simulator? error:"Could not find simulator for com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator"

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

the error message is "Could not find simulator for com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator"
i have just upgrade my macOS to 10.12 , and i'm using the Xcode 7.1 beta . i have load the iOS 8.2 simulator

Answer (score 0):

After I upgraded my Xcode to the newest 8.1, all thing works well!
So I guess it's the question of the old Xcode 7.1 beta.